# Size substitution with fontsize=14

Tags: koma-script, fontsize

I get the following warnings because of (I think) the asterisk produced by \footnote in the title.

> Font shape `U/rsfs/m/n' in size <29.86> not available size <24.88> substituted on input line 10.
>
> Font shape `U/rsfs/m/n' in size <14.93> not available size <14.4> substituted on input line 10.

```
\documentclass[version=last, DIV=calc, fontsize=14pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
\title{Title\footnote{This is an author version.}}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Can I get rid of this warning? Currently I [silence](https://ctan.org/pkg/silence) it, but is there a more elegant solution?

I use `mathrsfs` for `\mathscr`. I could replace it with something else if a better solution is recommended.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `mathrsfs`? This causes the warning and seems not to use a scaleable font.

Comment: @TeXnician thx for the comment. I added the reason for `mathrsfs` in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the contents of `ursfs.fd`:

```
\ProvidesFile{ursfs.fd}[1998/03/24 rsfs font definition file (jk)]
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{rsfs}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{%
   <5> <6> rsfs5
   <7> rsfs7
   <8> <9> <10> <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> rsfs10
}{}
```

which means that the font is only defined at the indicated sizes. On the other hand, a Type1 version has long been available, so it make sense to do, in your document that uses nonstandard font sizes,

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{rsfs}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{%
   <-6.5> rsfs5
   <6.5-8> rsfs7
   <8-> rsfs10
}{}
```

The code should go in your document preamble.

Full example.

```
\documentclass[version=last, DIV=calc, fontsize=14pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{rsfs}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{%
   <-6.5> rsfs5
   <6.5-8> rsfs7
   <8-> rsfs10
}{}

\begin{document}
\title{Title\footnote{This is an author version.}}
\author{Author}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```